# How to stop exposing source code of react in developer tools of browser?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, google-developer-tools

I'm developing project in ASP.NET Core and React. In testing, I came across one big security issue. Source files of react get expose in google developer tools. I have tried [to remove webpack source maps](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2787) but that thing didn't work for me and the reason is they have not mentioned in which webpack folder do we need to make change as there are 6 folder containing webpack. I'm new to this stack and not getting how to deal with this flaw. How can I fix this issue?

[image: Screenshot of Google Developer Tools]

Comment: All clientside code is exposed. Treat it so, there is no remedy for that. Keep any secrets serverside.

Comment: Well, you can't just remove the code from the browser, the browser needs the code to be there. You need to mangle, minify, and bundle your code. And as @Amadan said, any secrets should be on the server.

Comment: @Baruch: Mangling, minifying and bundling can be reversed (except for local variable names). One should not depend on [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Anyone moderately determined and competent will not be defeated by minification.

Comment: @Amadan Yes clientside code gets expose but lots of logic resides in client code including information about cookies, values stored in localstorage and the logic of how those values are mapped is also resides in that code and exposing complete file would be big threat

Comment: @Baruch Minification code can be reversed.

Comment: Then rethink what you want to put into cookies and localsorage, and move the logic to the server. There is _no way_ to secure the clientside info. Everything your browser knows, the user of the browser can know as well.

Comment: @Amadan Does removing sourcemaps would work?

Comment: No. This is not a matter of source maps, nor is it particular to React — it is the fact of life in any client-server architecture. Never tell the client anything you're not willing for the client user to know. E.g. one might ask "why do they allow hacking in League of Legends / Dark Souls / <any online game>", but the game is a client, and a sufficiently determined hacker can always subvert it. The only way to be secure is keeping your secrets in the server.

Comment: Your production build will not show the codings in developer tools. You can configure those in webpack

Comment: @karthikvishnukumar how can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this link https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

Comment: My guess is that you don't include source maps when you [publish your app with release config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21). Everyone telling you you should mess with webpack config must have missed that you have an asp.net app. Without sourcemaps the browser still has all your code so you should not store secret information in JavaScript; with or without minification or source maps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its very easy and its possible to hide complete source code which gets expose to end user in developer tools. You need to update `package.json` file from `ClientApp` folder.

**Before updation**

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",    //UPDATE THIS LINE
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
```

You need to use following code instead of above code:

**After updation**

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts build && rimraf ./build/**/*.map",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
```

Above code worked for me. This [thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2787) helped me in achieving my goal. For more details you can check that as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. This is how I fixed it.
Create a file called `.env` in the `src` folder then add this code `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`. Then run `npm run build` or `yarn run build`. This solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

if you are using craco to build your project, use this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && craco build && rimraf ./build/**/*.map",
  }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add new files to the project or remove .map files; you can also just set the environment variable *GENERATE_SOURCEMAP* to *false* either manually or by adding it to package.json before the *build* command:

**Modifying package.json**

Before:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    ...
  },
```

After:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    ...
  },
```

**Manually**

Run `export GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` before building in the same terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can never hide your code on the browser. The best you can do is obfuscate your code. Here is a very useful video that explains your concern: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOtZhNb4TKg
Also, use this as your reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build

The crux of the above video is to keep your business logic and secrets on the server which is always secure.

Comment: Thank you for the video and link. I've seen that video which is saying what I'm asking is impossible. Better to keep secret code at server side is what that video saying. I'll check that documentation as well.